# Why create 'new xml file' does not exist in Kepler 4.3?

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-mdt

I am using Eclipse Modeling Tools  `Version: Kepler Service Release 2` `Build id: 20140224-0627` for programming in Java

so, I would like to create new XML file as illustrated in the following link:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_create_xml_file.htm

but this option not exist. This problem also regarded for Eclipse Juno in [this stackoverflow entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175400/why-create-new-xml-file-option-not-exist)

I tried to resolve the similar issue using the answers in the above link. I am trying to install  "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" from Help ->  Install New Software using the "The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/kepler" in the "Work with" field. However, the installation is ignored as I have the newer version of "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools" & "Eclipse XML Editors and Tools SDK".

Why? I wonder how I could resolve the missing create 'new xml file' issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to install "XML Editors and Tools" from Help => Install New Software using the -- All Available Website -- in the "Work with" field. I checked the latest version of WTP and WTP SDK. That worked.